# WP_Query isn't working when 'tag' arg is passed

Tags: php, tags, taxonomy, wordpress

My first question :) I want to show posts from custom post type with specific tag. I am using `'tag' => 'slug'` but it doesn't work. I can't use categories, it must be filtered by tags. This is my code:

```
            $args = array(
                'numberposts' => 2,
                'post_type' => 'poslovi-oglasi',
                'tag' => 'javascript',
                'orderby' => 'rand',
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'tip_oglasa',
                        'value' => 'premium',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'tip_oglasa',
                        'value' => 'standard',
                    )
                )                                   
            );          

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        echo '<aside id="single-jobs" style="line-height: 100%;">';

        if ($the_query->have_posts()):  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

            echo '
                <div style="float: left; width: 50px;">
                    <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '?psl=wgt' . get_the_ID() . '">
                        <img src="'; $image = get_field('logo_single'); echo $image['url']; echo '" height="50" width="50">
                    </a>
                </div>
                 <div style="float: right; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 25px; width: 160px;">                       
                    <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '?psl=wgt' . get_the_ID() . '">
                        <h2><span>' . get_the_title() . '</span></h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="single-jobs-location" style="color: #bbb;">' . get_field('ime_firme') . '</div>
                    <div class="single-jobs-location">
                        <a href="http://startit.rs/poslovi/"' . get_field('lokacija_pozicije') . '" style="color: #888;">' . get_field('lokacija_pozicije') . '</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>';
        endwhile; endif;
```

When I delete tag `'tag' => 'javascript',` posts are showing, but all posts form that post type, not posts with specific tag.

Please help and thank you

Comment: are you sure you have a `post_type` of "poslovi-oglasi" with the "javascript" tag and either of the "tip_oglasa" values? Your arguments look correct.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It looks correct to me too, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I even tried to do it with categroies, just for test, and same thing happened

Comment: What if you remove the meta_query?

Comment: Nothing :p Strange, it only works with `'category_name' => 'slug'`, but as I said, I need to filter posts by tags not categories. So that isn't solution. Thank you anyway

Comment: Both tags and categories are taxonomies, so it's weird that one would work and not the other....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution! Somebody registered tag taxonomy for that post type with this slug 'oznaka'. So I just changed `'tag' => 'slug'` to `'oznaka' => 'slug'` and it works.

That site I needed this code for is one very complex custom WordPress website that is built by few seniors who worked on it before me. So I missed that little thing, it's probably tribute to inexperience.

Thanks to doublesharp I knew that I am on good path so I continued to search for an answer